# Jasper Report can not run with jar file

Tags: java, jasper-reports, nosuchmethoderror

While run in NetBeans it runs perfectly but when build and go to dist and run executable jar file report cannot run. Then I tried to run in cmd I got an error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init> (Z) V
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the version of ASM library is different when program runs inside NetBeans and when run in cmd. Review your project setup and ensure that your IDE setup matches your standalone setup.

Comment: Problem Solved...  
i removed all jasper libraries  and  install ireport 5.6.0 after installation 
i add libraries in netbeans where ireport  installed  Path is :
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-5.6.0\ireport\modules\ext